# Mouse cursor movement issue ('jumps') on large screens

Tags: display, mouse

I have a very large screen for my PC (49", 60FPS, 4K, Sony "Professional Display") where the 60fps limit is a real problem for the mouse cursor.
Since I have 6 screens in total, and don't want to spend my life moving the mouse cursor from one end to the other, I have to set it to move relatively fast (4300dpi, cursor speed at 50% in the mouse settings in Windows 10).

When I - by my standards - move it 'slowly' from one end of the screen to the other in 1 second, the cursor will do 64-pixel 'jumps'.
But typically I move it much faster, and that means that the "jumps" will become so big (300px, 500px, or even more), that I often cannot see it anymore. And have to 'search' for it afterwards.

Is there anything I can do - apart from buying a 120Hz monitor - to improve that?
Is there a tool that can create a kind of motion blur? Anything I can do so that I don't have to search for my mouse cursor constantly?

Mouse trails don't help, they make it worse for me.

Comment: Can you try a completely different mouse surface? My mousemat was turning slightly reflective and would occasionally do this until a bought a new one

Answer (score 0):

Using answer space to provide image...

Does Win 10 still have this control panel for pointer options?

<sup>Pic from Win 7</sup>
[image]

I'd set 'Enhance precision' to make it less twitchy at low speed, then either or both of 'pointer trails' [which used to be good for old LCD laptops with really low refresh rates] or the 'Show location with Ctrl'.